# La « boum » : d'où ça vient, est-ce vieilli, équivalents familiers etc. ?

Tags: étymologie, registre-familier, origine-ou-raison, synonymes

Le substantif (la) *boum* [(Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/boum#Nom_commun_2), [Larousse](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/boum/10584?q=boum#10452) ; n. f., et la [*surboum*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/surboum) par apocope de *suprise-partie*) dans le sens de la « fête accompagnée de musique, organisée par ou pour des adolescents et jeunes adultes » (Wiktionnaire) , d'où ça vient, peut-on dire que c'est de l'« argot des jeunes », est-ce relié à [*s'éclater*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/s_%C3%A9clater/27566?q=s%27%C3%A9clater#27420) et comment ; *Larousse* le dit *vieilli*, est-ce le cas (est-ce le cas de *s'éclater* aussi ?), depuis quand, et le cas échéant quel nom plus usuel le supplanterait dans l'usage avec ce registre-là (populaire/familier) ?

Comment: C'est plutôt vieilli... Les adolescents utilisent plutôt _"Faire la teuf (verlan de fête)"_ de nos jours.

Comment: Oh, j'avais mal lu la question je pense. Pour désigner une fête musicale, le mot ne me choquerait pas.

Comment: Entre [Sophie Marceau](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Boum) et [Les Forbans](https://www.paroles.net/les-forbans/paroles-chante), tout cela ne nous rajeunit pas...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Origines selon [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boum_(f%C3%AAte)):

> Le mot est apparu dès les années 1950 initialement sous la forme « surboum » (dérivée de « surprise-partie »)1, rapidement abrégée en « boum » (ou boom) tout court. L'apparition de cette abréviation pourrait avoir été encouragée par la popularité du célèbre Boom HEC organisé par les étudiants de HEC.

### Usages

*"Organiser une boum"* passerait pour moi (mais pas *"faire la boum"*!), utilisé par un adulte en parlant à d'autres adultes.

Selon [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boum_(f%C3%AAte)), cette obsolescence proviendrait d'un "sur-usage" :

> Le grand succès de ce film ["La boum" de Claude Pinoteau - 1980] a fait tomber en désuétude le mot « boum », victime en quelque sorte d'un excès de divulgation. Il a alors disparu du vocabulaire adolescent pour être remplacé par le terme plus souple et générique « fête », auquel a succédé « teuf » dans les années 1990.

Pour l'expression *"S'éclater"*, ce terme est encore très utilisé par toutes les tranches d'âge:

> Allez viens, on va s'éclater!

Il n'a pas de connotation argotique, et sera compris comme *"S'amuser follement"*. Il se marie bien avec le mot *boum* :

> J'organise une boum chez moi! Tu viendras? Tu verras, on va s'éclater!

Comment: I'd even say that the term "boum" was used prior to 2005... There is a popular french comedy film called "La Boum" (1980) that made Sophie Marceau famous. As a 27 year-old person, the term "boum" was already outdated back in 2007 (I was in high school  back then).

Comment: @SivaDashq Très vrai! Je suis en train de rechercher plus précisement les premiers emplois du mot, j'ai retiré cette période de temps de ma réponse pour l'instant

Comment: Mes parents (nés en 1946 et 1948) m'ont souvent parlé de "boum" ou "surboum" pour parler des soirées dansantes de leur jeunesse (donc, déjà dans les années 60).

Comment: @SivaDashq Selon [Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boum_(f%C3%AAte)), ce serait ce film qui aurait justement contribué à faire tomber le mot en désuétude, victime du phénomène "Je ne fais pas comme les autres, donc si tout le monde utilise ce mot je vais être différent".

Comment: @Améraldor Je suis triste, j'ai du supprimer tout ce que j'avais écrit... Parce que Wikipédia le dit mieux que moi et plus précisément x)

Comment: Soyez sans craintes, l'outil conserve [tout](https://french.stackexchange.com/revisions/28959/3) ! :) En passant, savez-vous pourquoi c'est _teuf_ et non pas _tef_ pour fête en verlan ? Merci !

Comment: @Améraldor En verlan, on accentue souvent la dernière syllabe du mot avant l'inversion, donc on inverse _"feh - teu"_. On diminue parfois la nouvelle fin de mot pour "accélérer" le mot, donc on dit _"teuf"_ et non pas "_teufê"_, de même qu'on dit _"Reup"_ pour pêre et non _"repeh"_.